# Increase JVM Heap Space in Springxd container and UI

Tags: hadoop, jvm, heap-memory, spring-xd

We are using SpringXD in production. Sink is Kafka. How to set/increase JVM heap space for a container as well as Admin-UI. what is the parameter to set and where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the below property to your `xd-container` and `xd-admin` files under the `XD_HOME/xd/bin` folder

```
DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS="-Xms 256m -Xmx 1g"
```